# Custom data validation formula for an invoice

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have created a formula which limits the input to a cell  , the created formula is as follows :

`=AND(FIND("-",F5,1)=3,1*LEFT(F5,FIND("-",F5,1)-1)<13,1*LEFT(F5,FIND("-",F5,1)-1)>=1,ISNUMBER(1*RIGHT(F5,LEN(F5)-FIND("-",F5,1))))`

My invoice number format is : "00-000" basis, The formula prevent any alphabetical input given . what i want to do is to enable alphabetical inputs to the Right part (000).

Comment: Simply delete this part from the formula: `ISNUMBER(1*RIGHT(F5,LEN(F5)-FIND("-",F5,1)))` Or do you want to avoid special signs as well `!@#$@#$<>>`?

Comment: @Vityata Hi many thanks. Yes i would want to avoid special signs as well

Comment: Minor comment:  If the left 2 digits are both 0, then your code gives `False` - e.g. `01-0000` is valid input, but `00-1234` is not...

Comment: Hi @Chronocidal I was only illustrating the format. left digit can not be 00 it should be between 01 to 12 only

Answer (score 0):

This formula will be `TRUE` if your input only contains Letters, Numbers, and hyphens:

```
=(SUMPRODUCT(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(F5),{"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","-","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"},"")))=36*LEN(F5))
```

It uses `SUMPRODUCT` to find the lengths of your input (`UPPER(F5)`) with each of the 37 characters (`"A"-"Z"`:26 + `"0"-"9"`: 10 + `"-"`:1) and add them together.  If *every* character in the string has been replaced once (i.e. they are all in that list of 37) then this total length will be **36** times the length of the original string (each character appears once for each of the 36 times it *isn't* replaced)

To add/remove valid characters, add/remove them in the {Array}, and adjust the `36` up or down to be 1 less than the number of characters you accept.